# MVC3 : subclassing a dataAnnotations attribute

Tags: attributes, asp.net-mvc-3

I have this working perfectly

```
[Required(Commissaires-priseuses = "ValidationError_Required", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources.Resources))]
public string Title { get; set; }
```

To shorten it, I decided to create a derved attribute from RequiredAttribute

```
public class LRequiredAttribute : System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.RequiredAttribute
{
    public LRequiredAttribute()
    {
        AllowEmptyStrings         = false;
        ErrorMessageResourceName  = "ValidationError_Required";
        ErrorMessageResourceType  = typeof(Resources.Resources);
    }
}
```

However, this won't work in **MVC3** ( It is used to work in **MVC2**)

```
[LRequired] 
public string Title { get; set; }
```

It is exactly the same and I cannot understand why it is working in the first case and not working in the second case

Thank you for your help

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "not working".

Answer (score 1):

My error was related to something else I just found
I forgort to uncomment registration of my client adapter

DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider.RegisterAdapter(typeof(LRequiredAttribute),    typeof(RequiredAttributeAdapter));